# Phalcon performance related queries

Tags: php, mysql, json, phalcon

I'm building a REST API for the output of endpoint /projects I have created 2 models:

Projects:

```
class Projects extends BaseModel
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->hasMany('id', 'Participants', 'projectId');
    }
}
```

Participants:

```
class Participants extends BaseModel
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->belongsTo('projectId', 'Projects', 'id');
    }
}
```

Lets say, I have 10 projects: (1 query)

```
$results = Projects::find();
```

I loop through all 10 of them, but I want all Participants too:

```
foreach($results as $result) {
    echo $result->participants; // 1 query
}
```

So at the end of the loop Phalcon has made an extra query for each project.

These queries were made by accessing $result->participants while iterating over 10 projects:

```
SELECT IF(COUNT(*)>0, 1 , 0) FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`TABLES` WHERE `TABLE_NAME`='projects'
DESCRIBE `projects`
SELECT `projects`.`id`, `projects`.`title`, `projects`.`client`, `projects`.`color`, `projects`.`start_date`, `projects`.`end_date`, `projects`.`notes`, `projects`.`stateId`, `projects`.`created_at`, `projects`.`updated_at` FROM `projects`
SELECT IF(COUNT(*)>0, 1 , 0) FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`TABLES` WHERE `TABLE_NAME`='project_participants'
DESCRIBE `project_participants`
SELECT `project_participants`.`id`, `project_participants`.`project_id`, `project_participants`.`user_id`, `project_participants`.`user_role_id`, `project_participants`.`user_state_id`, `project_participants`.`updated_at`, `project_participants`.`created_at` FROM `project_participants` WHERE `project_participants`.`project_id` = :0
SELECT `project_participants`.`id`, `project_participants`.`project_id`, `project_participants`.`user_id`, `project_participants`.`user_role_id`, `project_participants`.`user_state_id`, `project_participants`.`updated_at`, `project_participants`.`created_at` FROM `project_participants` WHERE `project_participants`.`project_id` = :0
SELECT `project_participants`.`id`, `project_participants`.`project_id`, `project_participants`.`user_id`, `project_participants`.`user_role_id`, `project_participants`.`user_state_id`, `project_participants`.`updated_at`, `project_participants`.`created_at` FROM `project_participants` WHERE `project_participants`.`project_id` = :0
SELECT `project_participants`.`id`, `project_participants`.`project_id`, `project_participants`.`user_id`, `project_participants`.`user_role_id`, `project_participants`.`user_state_id`, `project_participants`.`updated_at`, `project_participants`.`created_at` FROM `project_participants` WHERE `project_participants`.`project_id` = :0
SELECT `project_participants`.`id`, `project_participants`.`project_id`, `project_participants`.`user_id`, `project_participants`.`user_role_id`, `project_participants`.`user_state_id`, `project_participants`.`updated_at`, `project_participants`.`created_at` FROM `project_participants` WHERE `project_participants`.`project_id` = :0
SELECT `project_participants`.`id`, `project_participants`.`project_id`, `project_participants`.`user_id`, `project_participants`.`user_role_id`, `project_participants`.`user_state_id`, `project_participants`.`updated_at`, `project_participants`.`created_at` FROM `project_participants` WHERE `project_participants`.`project_id` = :0
SELECT `project_participants`.`id`, `project_participants`.`project_id`, `project_participants`.`user_id`, `project_participants`.`user_role_id`, `project_participants`.`user_state_id`, `project_participants`.`updated_at`, `project_participants`.`created_at` FROM `project_participants` WHERE `project_participants`.`project_id` = :0
SELECT `project_participants`.`id`, `project_participants`.`project_id`, `project_participants`.`user_id`, `project_participants`.`user_role_id`, `project_participants`.`user_state_id`, `project_participants`.`updated_at`, `project_participants`.`created_at` FROM `project_participants` WHERE `project_participants`.`project_id` = :0
SELECT `project_participants`.`id`, `project_participants`.`project_id`, `project_participants`.`user_id`, `project_participants`.`user_role_id`, `project_participants`.`user_state_id`, `project_participants`.`updated_at`, `project_participants`.`created_at` FROM `project_participants` WHERE `project_participants`.`project_id` = :0
```

### Question

*Is there a way to query the relations before hand, so it will be one query.
When I use the Query Builder provided by Phalcon I cannot access ->participants the same way.*

### Edit

I ended up using Query Builder, namespacing all columns

```
$builder = $modelsManager->createBuilder();
$builder->columns($columns)
        ->from('Projects')
        ->leftJoin('Participants')
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();
```

Columns like so:

```
Projects.id as projects_id
...
Participants.id as participants_id
Participants.projectId as participants_projectId
```

Because accessing ->participants on the result created by the Query Builder, did extra queries too.

Comment: Will Phalcon show you the CREATE TABLE and the SELECTs?  If so, please show us.

Comment: @RickJames I added a log of SELECT queries

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To access ->participants the same way using QueryBuilder, you will have to build join into Query.

Code example could be something like:

```
$queryBuilder = $this->getDI()->getModelsManager()
    ->createBuilder()
    ->columns(['p.id','participants.*'])
    ->addFrom('Entity\Projects', 'p')
    ->leftJoin('Entity\Participants', 'participants.projectId = p.id', 'participants')
    ->groupBy('p.id, participants.id')
    ->orderBy('p.id ASC');

$resultSet = $queryBuilder->getQuery()->execute();
```

`groupBy()` by is used here for making result possibly multi-dimensional.

That kind of query (tested under PgSQL) made Phalcon create some subsequent ResultSet objects of participants `pi` inside Resultsets for projects `p`.

You still can iterate through it by using `foreach()` but after all, **I'am not sure it did reduce final query count**.

Fireing `$result = $resultSet->toArray()` made `$result['pi']` remain as Resultset, so u should stay cautious on that. **You may force it to dump as arrays by defining exact columns in `columns()` parameters.** It has its downside - you will no longer profit from `groupBy()`, at least on Phalcon 1.3.2 and PHP 5.5.3 im running here.

Comment: (1) WHERE  `project_participants`.`project_id` = :0 -- looks syntactically incorrect -- What's up?  (2) How big is `project_participants`?  (3) SHOW CREATE TABLE `project_participants`;  (4) what the heck is this about?  SELECT IF(COUNT(*)>0, 1 , 0) FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`TABLES`...?

Comment: Prolly builder is collecting some informaton for i cant tell why.Format of `project_id = :0` is related with Phalcon using PDO and builds representation of PhQL having wildcards in it. To get exact queries you should retrieve logs from your SQL server itself (unless you did that?). To not fire those `INFORMATION_SHEMA` over and over again you may want to use some cache of metadata but im not sure it will help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great library for eager loading on phalcon.

[stibiumz phalcon eager loading](https://github.com/stibiumz/phalcon.eager-loading)

That library solves the N + 1 queries for relationships. It is already included on the phalcon incubator. I'm using it on production already.

What it does is create a query using the IN clause and filling the models with the results.

On a has many it does:

```
SELECT * FROM main
SELECT * FROM related WHERE x.id IN (results from the previous resultset)
```