# Phalcon | One query insted of two for "belongsTo"

Tags: php, mysql, join, phalcon, belongs-to

Is it possible to make one JOIN-query instead of two SELECT-queries if a model has relation belongsTo?

I mean that if there's two models:

```
<?php

class Robots extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{
    public $id;

    public $name;

    public $type_id;

    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->belongsTo("type_id", "RobotsTypes", "id");
    }

}
```

and

```
<?php

class RobotsTypes extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{

    public $id;

    public $type;

}
```

And I'm trying to get robot type:

```
$robot = Robots::findFirst(2);
echo $robot->RobotsTypes->type;
```

Then Phalcone makes two SELECT-queries:

```
150312 14:41:02 49 Connect robots@localhost on robots
49 Query SELECT IF(COUNT(*)>0, 1 , 0) FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`TABLES` WHERE `TABLE_NAME`='robots'
49 Query DESCRIBE `robots`
49 Query SELECT `robots`.`id`, `robots`.`name`, `robots`.`type_id` FROM `robots` WHERE `robots`.`id` = '2' LIMIT 1
49 Query SELECT IF(COUNT(*)>0, 1 , 0) FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`TABLES` WHERE `TABLE_NAME`='robot_types'
49 Query DESCRIBE `robot_types`
49 Query SELECT `robot_types`.`id`, `robot_types`.`type` FROM `robot_types` WHERE `robot_types`.`id` = '2' LIMIT 1
49 Quit
```

Is it possible to make Phalcon execute just 1 query with JOIN?

```
SELECT `robots`.`id`, `robots`.`name`, `robots`.`type_id`, `robot_types`.`id`, `robot_types`.`type` FROM `robots` JOIN `robot_types` ON `robots`.`type_id` = `robot_types`.`id` WHERE `robots`.`id` = '2' LIMIT 1
```

I know that using views can solve the problem. But it needs to create a view and one more model.

Is it possible to do this only in Phalcone without using PHQL? For exmaple, by specifying addition argument in belongsTo method?

It's similar with [Phalcon performance related queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28755079/phalcon-performance-related-queries)

Thanks :)

Comment: I think it's reason, why query builder exists. Models are for fast finds, queryBuilder is for complex solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$queryBuilder = $this->getDI()->getModelsManager()
    ->createBuilder()
    ->columns(['r.id','r.name', 'r.type_id', 'rt.type'])
    ->addFrom('Robot', 'r')
    ->leftJoin('RobotTypes', 'rt.id = r.type_id', 'rt');

$resultSet = $queryBuilder->getQuery()->execute();//->toArray(); //optional
```

If you call by name all columns you need, you should be able to retrieve full result w/o multiquerying DB for types separately. It's still not a PHQL, it also does not require declarations of `belongsTo()` to work properly.

As far as i know, you're not able to fetch joinable things only using models - It's because implementation would be too complex in case of multirelational tables, and thats for what `queryBuilder` is designed.