# Phalcon Model find() with condition in another table

Tags: php, phalcon

so I have 2 tables like this

```
books
id        name       status_id
-------------------------------
1         a          0
2         b          2
...

status
id        description
---------------------
0         borrowed
1         available
2         lost
```

Phalcon models

```
class Books extends ModelBase {

    public function initialize() {
        $this -> belongsTo("status_id", "Status", "id");
    }
}

class Status extends ModelBase {
    public function initialize() {
        $this -> hasMany('id', "Books", 'status_id');
    }
}
```

I would like to extract all books that has status description "lost". This is what I have so far:

```
$lostBooks = Books::find(
    'conditions' => "description=:status:",
    'bind' => array(
        'status' => 'lost'
    ),
);
```

Update:
I got what I want through a workaround

```
$lostStatus = Status::findFirst("description='Closed'");
$lostBooks = Books::find(
    'conditions' => "status_id=:id:",
    'bind' => array(
        'id' => $lostStatus -> id
    ),
);
```

However I feel like I'm not using the intended way to execute these kind of tasks, so if you have a better one, please answer below.

Comment: You have all you need already in answers, just try them. Both are correct.

Comment: thanks a lot, I can't seem to find a lot of answers for Phalcon, not sure if it is not popular, or just too straight forward and I'm not smart enough.

Comment: Phalcon is specific and born for wildly fast and hudge at same time services. Narrow range of users and lack of tips&trick online grows us experts, what I feel OK with ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have possible two approaches:

## 1. Via `queryBuilder`

Joins directly from models are hard to achieve. It's why `queryBuilder` was designed - models are querying for data only if you are willing to get them, eg. by accessing supposedly-joined `$books->getStatus()`. For more information search documentations: [hudge example](http://docs.phalconphp.com/pl/latest/api/Phalcon_Mvc_Model_Query_Builder.html). There was also an useful topic about optimisations [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28755079/phalcon-performance-related-queries), so you will know why not always direct usage of models is good idea.

## 2. Via creating a separate model

To make it easy, clear but maybe not most performance-wise (depends on usage), since not long ago (Phalcon 1.3.2?) you can create a separate model with [additional conditions](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues/926#issuecomment-59306481) in it (not tested example):

```
class LostBooks extends Books {

    public function initialize() {
       $this -> belongsTo("status_id", "Status", "id",
       [
            'alias' => 'status',
            'params' => [
                'description' => 'lost'
            ]
       ]);
    }
}
```

With that properly declarated you can get those simple by

```
$lostBooks = LostBooks::find();
```

PS: use `array()` instead `[]` of, if you are previous to PHP 5.4, got some habits.

Comment: It was 5.4 that short array syntax  [] was introduced. If he doesn't need to support 5.3 and below then he doesn't need to worry. Which is a good thing, because PHP doesn't officially support 5.3 and below...

Answer (score 1):

```
class Books extends ModelBase {

    public function initialize() {
        $this->belongsTo('status_id', 'Status', 'id');
    }

}

class Status extends ModelBase {

    public function initialize() {
        $this->hasMany('id', 'Books', 'status_id', 
            array('alias' => 'books')
        );
    }

}

$lostBooks = Status::findFirst("description = 'lost'")->getBooks();

$lostBooks = Status::findFirst("description = 'lost'")->books;
```

Comment: Third possible approach ;) But produces one extra query.