# Phalcon - How do i do a SELECT IN Subquery with Phalcon models?

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller, phalcon

I need to know how to do i do a subquery type selection with phalcon models?

for example i want to select all the users who viewed me, they are stored in the UserView table with columns 'id','user_from','user_to' (mapped by User table user_id to either user_from or user_to)

so i want to select all the users who has a user_to as with the current user, and group by user_to make sure i only get one recorded, I wrote below function to do this but there is fundamental two problems

**1. Is how to do sub-query using phalcon models**

**2. Is my logic correctly applied on the back-end of the DB (as i cant see real executed query)**

```
public function getUserWithViewedMe($limit=1000000){
        return  User::query()
            ->rightJoin("XYZ\Models\UsersView")
            ->andWhere(" XYZ\Models\UsersView.user_from IN :user_id: ",
                              array('user_id' => $this->user->user_id) )
            ->group('user_id')
            ->order("XYZ\Models\UsersView.id DESC ")
            ->limit($limit)
            ->execute();
    }
```

This returns empty set...

Answer (score 1):

So far it is not possible to model subqueries in Phalcon. There is also [topic](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues/10453) according to standard implementation issues.

To query params according to other table, [here is an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29840462/phalcon-model-find-with-condition-in-another-table/29840857#29840857).

To query `IN` you can use queryBuilder

```
$this->modelsManager->createBuilder()
    // ...
    ->inWhere('column', $array);
```