# Phalcon How to do SELECT not in with SUB QUERY in query manager?

Tags: mysql, model-view-controller, phalcon

I like to know how do i use select not in as a subquery in phalcon

for example i know i can use following to do the notIn with a array values.

```
return User::query()
               ->where(" gender!=:gender: ", array('gender' => $gender))
               ->andWhere(" verify=1 ")
               ->notInWhere('user_id', "SELECT user_id FROM user_bannned WHERE user_id=:user_id:" )
               ->order(" last_visit DESC ")
               ->limit($limit)
               ->execute();
```

Problem is

**"SELECT user_id FROM user_bannned WHERE user_id=:user_id:"**

how do i do this 
subquery with model query manager ?

ANY ideas ? or workarounds ?

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33772911/phalcon-how-do-i-do-a-select-in-subquery-with-phalcon-models/33777183#33777183) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33446366/phql-where-xxx-in-can-get-only-1-data/33823669#33823669).

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is your problem ?

Just do the same:

```
$this->modelsManager->createBuilder()
    ->from(['User'=>'User Namespace'])
    ->where("gender != :gender:,array('gender'=>$gender))
    ->andWhere("verify=1")
    ->notInWhere('user_id', "SELECT user_id FROM user_banned WHERE user_id = :user_id:")
    ->order("last_visit DESC")
    ->limit($limit)
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute();
```

Thats it.

Comment: i get a error Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Criteria::notInWhere() must be of the type array, string given, called in