# Phalcon and Postgresql use different db source

Tags: database, postgresql, orm, phalcon

It is possible in one `\Phalcon\Mvc\Model` use different db source depends on db operation? I would like for `SELECT`s to use postgres db defined view and for `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE` as source use db table name. I know that it is possible to define in postgres `ON INSERT RULE` on view but I don't want to do that. I tried to override methods `save()` and `delete()` and set different source name `$this->setSource("DB_NAME");` but before executing the query Phalcon execute getSource() :)

Any idea?

Comment: why would you like to read from one table and write to another one?

Comment: If I have table with some relationship for example user have got one category, when I'm listing users on list I would like next to them display them group name. I can do this very simple using view, simple join group name to user view. In that place I don't need to have all group objects so i don't have to and don't want to use $user->getGroup()

Comment: You will end up easier and still performance-wise when using `queryBuilder`. Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28755079/phalcon-performance-related-queries/28769763#28769763) for more details.