# Phalcon speed query

Tags: oracle, performance, api, phalcon

Good day!

I test phalcon in my project. I thought, it's very faster then others.
But...

Look at my test

```
$app = new Micro($di);
$app->get('/', function () use ($app) {
    $users = $app->modelsManager->executeQuery("SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE NAME IN ('L488', '1K5T', '4QYS' , '9ECV')");
    $data = array();
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $data[] = array(
            'name' => $user
        );
    }
    echo json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
});
```

And my model

```
use Phalcon\Mvc\Model;

class TEST extends Model {

    public $name;

    public function initialize() {
        $this->setSource("TEST");
    }

}
```

The query execution time is  1.2-1.5 s. Now without phalcon

```
$user = 'name';
$pass = 'pass';

$dbh = new PDO('oci:dbname=orcl', $user, $pass);
$users = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE NAME IN ('L488', '1K5T', '4QYS' , '9ECV')");

$data = array();
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $data[] = array(
            'name' => $user
        );
    }

echo json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

The query execution time is  600-700 ms
WTF? How it can be? Why phalcon modelsManager slower

Answer (score 4):

This question has been [answered on the Phalcon forum.](https://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/11669/phalcon-speed-query)

> What you're testing here with Micro app is just database, not Phalcon. Your query kills RDBMS, that's not optimizied at all. Any overhead you might get is by using Phalcon's ORM, so yeah - ORM will always add overhead if you compare with plain PDO.  -- stamster

Comment: Also it is possible to [speed up this query anyway](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28755079/phalcon-performance-related-queries)